# Vert.x: Is there a difference between deploying a verticle n times vs setInstances(n)?

Tags: java, vert.x

Is there a major between doing

```
DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(2);
vertx.deployVerticle("com.mycompany.MyVerticle", options);
```

and

```
vertx.deployVerticle("com.mycompany.MyVerticle");
vertx.deployVerticle("com.mycompany.MyVerticle");
```

?

The [docs](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_specifying_number_of_verticle_instances) only mention the first approach.

In the `MyVerticle#start` method I read a file which creates a lock. So deploying with `.setInstances(2)` will cause an `IOException`. I want to deploy the next verticle only if the future of the first is completed.

Are there any downsides of the second approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a major difference: when you deploy several instances by configuring `DeploymentOptions`, Vert.x guarantees the verticle instances use different event loops (provided there are more event loops than instances to deploy).

If you have to create a specific resource that is shared by all verticle instances, you could create it in the main method of your application and then use the `deploy` method which takes a `Supplier` argument:

```
var sharedResource = setupSharedResource();
DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(2);
vertx.deployVerticle(() -> new com.mycompany.MyVerticle(sharedResource), options);
```

Comment: thanks for pointing to this! Is this also a problem if I plan my verticles to be worker verticles? The resource itself does all the processing work, so I need one for each verticle. (I could also copy the sharedResource in the verticle constructor but that is not straightforward). If I deploy the verticles one after another, can I somehow make sure they get in the same WorkerPool? Is this even desirable?

Comment: Worker verticles are also assigned an event loop which manages IO events. Only your verticle callbacks are invoked on worker threads. And for advice on how to design your verticles, I would recommend asking to one of the Vert.x community channels

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! Can I specify the event loop thread a verticle should be deployed on? Then I could spread the verticles manually. If I have 3 event loops and want to deploy 4 verticles sequentially I could do 1->1 2->2 3->3 4->1... (verticle -> event loop)

Comment: No, you can't do this.

Comment: another update: while it's may not guaranteed that the verticle instances use different event loops the different verticles are still launched on different event-loops in a round robin fashion

Answer (score 1):

When using `setInstances()` Vert.x will immediately start all instances "at the same time" (they nominally get started by different contexts with different worker threads, so multiple instances should not interact except using well defined non-vert.x multi-threading semantics).

That being said, there's nothing wrong with deploying multiple instances at different times, for example by registering for `onSuccess()` on the first `deployVerticle()` and call the second deploy from there - Vert.x doesn't care which verticles you deploy, as long as you never try to deploy the same instance multiple times.

So this should work fine:

```
vertx.deployVerticle("myverticle").onSuccess(v -> 
    vertx.deployVerticle("myverticle")).
```